# Error When Compiling c4iOS app in XCODE

Tags: c4

finally got reg'd as an iOS developer  - tried to compile the app i wrote for the iPAD. app runs fine in simulator, it throws this error when compiling.

here is the error
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/YourMom/Documents/_.programming/c4iOS_APPS/test2/test2/Library/libC4.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

current version:

https://github.com/dubpixel/test2

thanks

-jf

Comment: Downloading your project. Will let you know in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project -> Build Settings -> remove the arm7s architecture from "valid architectures"

this worked, and kept xcode from wondering where its second slice was!

Comment: The project i created with your code and media uses armv7. Glad you found what was wrong with it! I have to rebuild the installer, and this will help me figure out how to make it more solid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to mention that the project you're building is Universal. At the moment, only iPhone / iPad projects can be built with C4. The process for creating a Universal app project template is pretty complicated (and completely undocumented). A Universal template is something that's at the top of the to-do for the near future.

I checked your git'd Xcode project, and it wouldn't build for me either. So, I copied your code and media into a new C4 project, targeted for iPad... And, it worked! I was dragging back and forth and the movie's frames were changing.

Also, I noticed that your project included Unit Tests. I would suggest un-checking the Unit Test option when you're creating new C4 projects.

Comment: travis - so i essentially made a new project, this time being sure to select iPad (as i thought i had done before) - the issue is still persisting. I am in the process of git'ing the new version (TVtherapy) - it will be here when finished.   https://github.com/dubpixel/TVtherapy